# 2D integration by parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the 2D integral $$\iint_{xy}\psi\textbf{u}_H\cdot\nabla_Hh\,{\rm d}x{\rm d}y,$$ with $\psi = \psi(x, y)$, $\textbf{u}_H = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$, $\nabla_H = (\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y)$ and $h = h(x, y)$. Is there a 2D integration by parts equivalent, so that I can remove the differentiation of $h$?

Comment: Could you explain what all the symbols mean? It's not clear from your question, and it would be necessary to know in order to determine which assumptions or manipulations are reasonable.

Comment: What does the subscript $H$ denote on both $u_H$ and $\nabla_H$?  What is $\delta h$?

Comment: Added this information

Answer (score 7):

The integral seems to be of the form
$$
\iint_\Omega \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla f \, dA
$$

The integration by parts equivalent is to use
$$
\nabla \cdot (f \mathbf{v}) = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{v} + f (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})
$$
and then Stokes' theorem:
$$
\iint_\Omega \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla f \, dA
= \iint_\Omega \left( \nabla\cdot (f\mathbf{v}) - f (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}) \right) \, dA
= \iint_\Omega \nabla\cdot (f\mathbf{v}) \, dA - \iint_\Omega f (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})  \, dA \\
= \oint_{\partial\Omega} f\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds - \iint_\Omega f (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})  \, dA,
$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal on the boundary and $ds$ is boundary length measure.